# Access remotely to your IIS WebSite

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, router

I just created a website using IIS 7. The problem is that I cannot access it from a remote computer. I can access lets say, www.mywebpage4test.com in my own computer. I allowed the HTTP program in windows firewall. Also tried other port like 82, and opened too. I modified the host file from \drivers\etc and placed the following,

```
127.0.0.1   www.mywebpage4test.com
70.45.XX.XX www.mywebpage4test.com
```

where of course the xx I used real numbers. I am not sure if that ip is the browser or gateway IP...

I can use the ddns but, it do not seems to work neither; thus my computer is behind a router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My router (DIR-655) does not allow loop redirection. Thus if I want to access to my own website I need to use the internal ip.